# How to disable an input via PHP

Tags: php

So I have an input type radio and a select and I want to disable them via PHP because I have an IF in my PHP to know if I need to disable them or not.

```
if (isset($slide["id"])) {
$label = "Current user";
//disable the input radio and the select

}else{
$label = "A adicionar destaque";
 }
```

And the basic html

```
<input type="radio" id="type_galeria" name="type" value="1"  /> Galeria </label>´
<input type="radio" id="type_galeria2" name="type" value="2"  /> Galeria 2</label>
<select name="galeria_id" id="galeria_id" class="form-control select2">
 //and the options here...
```

So, that's it, just want to disable those 3. I have more inputs in the form but I just want to disable these 3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a variable to use the property 'disabled' in the elements, something like:

```
<?php
$status= isset($slide["id"]) ? 'disabled' : '';
?>
```

And then:

```
<input type="radio" id="type_galeria" name="type" value="1" <?=$status?> /> Galeria </label>´
<input type="radio" id="type_galeria2" name="type" value="2" <?=$status?> /> Galeria 2</label>
<select name="galeria_id" id="galeria_id" class="form-control select2" <?=$status?>>
```

Comment: Glad I could help!